# Remove exact rows and frequency of rows of a data.frame that are in another data.frame in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following two data.frames created using pandas in python 3:

```
a1 = pd.DataFrame(({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'b', 'd', 'b']}))
a2 = pd.DataFrame(({'A': [1, 2, 3, 2], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']}))
```

I would like to remove the exact rows of a1 that are in a2 so that the result should be:

```
A B
4 d
5 e
4 d
2 b
```

Note that one row with 2 b in a1 is retained in the final result (essentially only one of them gets canceled with the one in a2).  Is there any built-in function in pandas or any other library in python 3 to get this result?

Comment: The term for this is "set difference."  But unfortunately `pd.Index.difference()` doesn't suffice, despite it being meant for set differences.  I was hoping to use something like `pd.Index(a1).difference(a2)` but it doesn't deal with non-unique items properly.

Comment: John Zwinck I learnt about that `Index(a1)` today. Hope I completed your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets use groupby cumcount:

```
a1['count'] = a1.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
a2['count'] = a2.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
```

**Option 1** - merge and query

```
df = (pd.merge(a1,a2, indicator=True, how='left')
        .query("_merge != 'both'")
        .drop(['_merge','count'], 1))
```

**Option 2** - With index difference after merging i.e

```
i = a1.index.difference(a1.merge(a2,on=['A','B','count']).index)
df = a1.loc[i].drop('count',1)
```

**Option 3** - Completing @ John Zwinck's approach

```
df =pd.DataFrame(pd.Index(a1).difference(pd.Index(a2)).tolist(),columns=a2.columns).drop(['count'],1)
```

Output :

```
  A  B
3  4  d
4  5  e
6  4  d
7  2  b
```

Comment: Superb! It does give what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

By using the definition of `list` and `remove`

```
l1=a1.values.tolist()
l2=a2.values.tolist()
for x in l2:
    l1.remove(x)

pd.DataFrame(l1,columns=a1.columns)

Out[173]: 
   A  B
0  4  d
1  5  e
2  4  d
3  2  b
```

---

Time

---

Bharath's 
1st.

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
a1['count'] = a1.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
a2['count'] = a2.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
df = (pd.merge(a1,a2, indicator=True, how='left')
        .query("_merge != 'both'")
        .drop(['_merge','count'], 1))
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
0.012827654755454887
```

2nd.

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
a1['count'] = a1.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
a2['count'] = a2.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
i = a1.index.difference(a1.merge(a2,on=['A','B','count']).index)
df = a1.loc[i].drop('count',1)
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
0.05914717068662867
```

3rd.

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
a1['count'] = a1.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
a2['count'] = a2.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
df =pd.DataFrame(pd.Index(a1).difference(pd.Index(a2)).tolist(),columns=a2.columns).drop(['count'],1)
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
0.006586597486375467
```

---

Mine:

```
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
l1=a1.values.tolist()
l2=a2.values.tolist()
for x in l2:
    l1.remove(x)
pd.DataFrame(l1,columns=a1.columns)
print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
0.0028012795203835594
```

Data input 100 times of the sample.

```
a1=pd.concat([a1]*100,axis=0)
a2=pd.concat([a2]*100,axis=0)
```

Comment: Yes, it does give the result what I am looking for, but is there a way to avoid loops as my data.frames contain thousands and thousands of rows and about 10 columns.

Comment: If you think it is not efficient try to time it , and show us what you get . Do not be scared by those basic for loop , sometime they are even more efficiency.

Comment: I am very new to python. I have been using R quite extensively, but very recently (yesterday, in fact) I have started exploring python 3 and pandas library. In R, the looping statement had terribly slowed down my computation and I had to use dplyr package, with the help of stackoverflow community, to get it working without any looping statements. I was afraid this would be the case in python.

Comment: @RBL you can check the detail , and I am both R and Python user too , cheers

Comment: @Wen hard to beat the list removing solution. I agree

Comment: Superb! Appreciate the demonstration on time efficiency.

Comment: @RBL YW~ seems you are new to SO , you can upvote or accept those answers~

Comment: Not bad one is better than the other